# How can I Pass data from View Composer to View Components in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, components, laravel-7

I have a large navigation that needs to pull in data from my database.

I split the navigation up into 3 components so it's easier to work with.

```
<x-navigation.navigation/>
    |
    |
    <x-navigation.desktop.nav-desktop/> (Needs DB Query activeCountries & activeSponsorCountries)
    |
    |
    <x-navigation.mobile.nav-mobile/>  (Needs DB Query activeCountries & activeSponsorCountries)
```

---

I added Both Query to a View Composer since the navigation needs to access these at all times.

**This is the View Composer logic:** *(I can use these anywhere, BUT within the component for some reason..?)*

***ViewComposer > ActiveCountriesComposer.php***

```
class ActiveCountriesComposer {

    public $activeCountries = [];

    public function compose(View $view) {
        $this->activeCountries = Country::where('active', 1)->get(['id',...]);
        $view->with('activeCountries', $this->activeCountries);
    }
}
```

***ViewComposer > ActiveSponsorCountriesComposer.php***

```
class ActiveSponsorCountriesComposer {

    public $activeSponsorCountries = [];

    public function compose(View $view) {
        $this->activeSponsorCountries = Country::where('active', 1)
                ->whereHas('locations', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('sponsorship_country', '=', 1);
                })
                ->get(['id',...]);
        $view->with('activeSponsorCountries', $this->activeSponsorCountries);
    }
}
```

> I need to know how I can access the 2 View Composer queries inside
> `<x-navigation.desktop.nav-desktop/>` &
> `<x-navigation.mobile.nav-mobile/>`

---

Currently I have it working, but not with the View Composer... I have to make duplicate requests within the View Components.

**Both Component NavDesktop & NavMobile use repeat code:** *(NavMobile is the exact same)*

```
class NavDesktop extends Component
{
    public $activeCountries;
    public $activeSponsorCountries;
   

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->activeCountries = Country::where('active', 1)->get(['id',...]);

        $this->activeSponsorCountries = Country::where('active', 1)
                ->whereHas('locations', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('sponsorship_country', '=', 1);
                })
                ->get(['id',...]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.navigation.desktop.nav-desktop')->with('activeCountries','activeSponsorCountries');
    }
```

> Is there a way I can pass in the View Composer Queries to the root
> level component `<x-navigation.navigation/>` so it will allow the 2 components
> `<x-navigation.desktop.nav-desktop/>` &
> `<x-navigation.mobile.nav-mobile/>` to use those two queries from View Composer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Using Laravel 7+

Comment: To which views did you attach the two view composers?

Comment: @Remul I didn't attach them to anything. They're just global and I can access anywhere in the site by doing something like `@foreach($activeCountries as $ac) ...` I originally had that logic in the `ViewServiceProvdier`, but it was creating too many queries.

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked more into @Remul suggestion. I thought they were global and I thought wrong.

I simply forgot to register the navigation within the `ComposerServiceProvider`..

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
                ['components.navigation.navigation'],
                ActiveCountriesComposer::class
        );
        View::composer(
                ['components.navigation.navigation'],
                ActiveSponsorCountriesComposer::class
        );
```

Now I can pass the data to my components like this:

```
<x-navigation.navigation :activeCountries="$activeCountries" :activeSponsorCountries="$activeSponsorCountries"/>
```

‍♂️ So lesson learned. When you make single ViewComposer Files. Don't forget to register them in the ComposerServiceProvider.